# Flex3,Tree mapping by means of lines

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I want to connect one tree node with another tree node visually using lines. It's similar to mapping data items of two trees.

Comment: i have drawn a line , when i close the node line remain constant....when i expand or shrink a tree ,mapped line should move to correct position

Comment: You need to detect tree changes and update line. Simplest method - just measure line endpoints position every frame, if they change, line must be redrawn.

Answer (score 0):

You can use transparent layer (Sprite or Canvas) above trees to draw line there. Find nodes you need, get their absolute coordinates with `localToGlobal`, transform coordinates to line layer (with respect of layer origin on stage), and you can draw the line.

Comment: Was looking for something like this. Thanks! I'll let you know if it works.